# Discord.py API Bot: 2 arguments in function not working

Tags: python, discord

I have written a function called spam for my Discord bot using the discord.py API which should take an argument of msg and amount.

msg is just a string and amount is an integer (the amount of times to spam the msg string)

For some reason my bot only seems to be picking up on the msg argument not the amount

This is my code so far:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spam(ctx, *, msg, amount):
for x in range(0, amount):
    await bot.say(msg)
```

This code returns the error:

```
TypeError: spam() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'amount'
```

Any help on how to have 2 arguments would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What message are you putting in discord to call the bot?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering but the reason was the * in the arguments. It is supposed to always come 1 before the last argument.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spam(ctx, msg, *, amount):
for x in range(0, amount):
await bot.say(msg)
```

Would Work.